# Using inputs to reactively call a dataframe in a reactive list?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a simple shiny app that has lists loaded into it. I am trying to use some user inputs to call the data needed. Although when I use a `paste0` to create the name of the list and dataframe it is not being called.

As you can see below: I have two valueboxes. The first one I am just calling the full list/dataframe which is `Store1_2021$Bakery %>% nrow()`.

The second 1 I am using a paste0() function to try to replicate but its printing as text instead of calling the dataframe.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is best practice but if anyone has any solutions I would appreciate it.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

Store1_2021 <- list(Bakery = structure(list(Sales = c(23, 33, 124, 133), Item = c("Bread", 
                                                                                  "Bread", "Bread", "Torillas"), Units = c(1, 3, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                       -4L), class = "data.frame"), Electronics = structure(list(Sales = c(23, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           33, 124, 133), Item = c("Tv", "Tv", "Tv", "Speaker"), Units = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           3, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"))
Store2_2021 <- list(Bakery = structure(list(Sales = c(23, 133, 124, 23), Item = c("Bread", 
                                                                                  "Torillas", "Bread", "Bread"), Units = c(1, 3, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                       -4L), class = "data.frame"), Electronics = structure(list(Sales = c(23, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           33, 124, 12), Item = c("Speaker", "Tv", "Tv", "Speaker"), Units = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               3, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("store","Select Store:", choices = c(1,2)),
    selectInput("department", "Select Department:", choices = c("Bakery","Electronics"))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
    valueBoxOutput("box1"),
    valueBoxOutput("box2")

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  
  output$box1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      Store1_2021$Bakery %>% nrow()
      
      ,
      
      "No of Transactions (rows)",
      icon = icon("users"),
      color = "blue"
    )
  })
  
  output$box2 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      
      paste0("Store",input$store,"_2021","$",input$department)
      
      ,
      
      "No of Transactions (rows)",
      icon = icon("users"),
      color = "blue"
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your input data MUST be in this list format? it would be much easier in my opnion if u had a dataframe with store and departmant as variables..

Comment: I understand but that’s how I’m receiving the data.

Comment: I asked because of something like that. I was trying to create an answer based on a dafaframe containing the exact same information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

Store1_2021 <- list(Bakery = structure(list(Sales = c(23, 33, 124, 133), Item = c("Bread", 
                                                                                  "Bread", "Bread", "Torillas"), Units = c(1, 3, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                       -4L), class = "data.frame"), Electronics = structure(list(Sales = c(23, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           33, 124, 133), Item = c("Tv", "Tv", "Tv", "Speaker"), Units = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           3, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"))
Store2_2021 <- list(Bakery = structure(list(Sales = c(23, 133, 124, 23), Item = c("Bread", 
                                                                                  "Torillas", "Bread", "Bread"), Units = c(1, 3, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                       -4L), class = "data.frame"), Electronics = structure(list(Sales = c(23, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           33, 124, 12), Item = c("Speaker", "Tv", "Tv", "Speaker"), Units = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               3, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("store","Select Store:", choices = c(1,2)),
    selectInput("department", "Select Department:", choices = c("Bakery","Electronics"))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      valueBoxOutput("box1"),
      valueBoxOutput("box2")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  
  output$box1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      Store1_2021$Bakery %>% nrow()
      
      ,
      
      "No of Transactions (rows)",
      icon = icon("users"),
      color = "blue"
    )
  })
  
  mystore <- reactive({get(sprintf("Store%s_2021",input$store))})
  
  mydept <- eventReactive(c(mystore(),input$department), {
    mystore()[[input$department]]
  })
  
  output$box2 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      
      nrow(mydept())
      ,
      
      "No of Transactions (rows)",
      icon = icon("users"),
      color = "red"
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can you tell me how that `mystore <- reactive({get(sprintf("Store%s_2021",input$store))})` function works? Specifically what does the `s` after Store% do?

Comment: `%s` corresponds to the value of `input$store`. Then `get()` gets `Store1_2021` or `Store2_2021` depending on the value of `input$store`.

Answer (score 0):

Another alterntive could be

```
  output$box2 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      .GlobalEnv[[glue("Store{input$store}_2021")]][[input$department]] %>%
        nrow(),
      "No of Transactions (rows)",
      icon = icon("users"),
      color = "blue"
    )
  })
```